# jQuery data() type conversion issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, type-conversion

I have the following div `<div data-item-id="0234">` and when I try to access the data with `$element.data("itemId")` jQuery converts it to int and now i get `234` instead of `"0234"`. Is there any way i can get the actual data `"0234"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `.attr` instead (`$element.attr('data-item-id');`).  The docs themselves suggest this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$element.attr("data-item-id")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `attr`: http://jsbin.com/ipuhah/

```
$(selector).attr("data-item-id");
```